# Get index of an alias of foreach in Knockoutjs

Tags: html, knockout.js, foreach

I gave an alias for each data of the Knockout's foreach so I can call it inside another nested foreach.
Now I want to get the index of the alias. I tried '.index()' and '.$index' but no use.

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: subjects, as: 'subject' }-->
/*nested foreach*/
subject.index() <-- undefined
<!-- /ko-->
```

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use standart javascript function [Array.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: subjects, as: 'subject' }-->
/*nested foreach*/
  <span data-bind="text: subjects.indexOf(subject)"></span>
<!-- /ko-->
```

`$index` context value is possible to use only for non-virtual for-each, e.g.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: categories">
   <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
</ul>
```